# Node js can connect internally but not externally

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, nodemon

I am trying to connect to a js file on a local server. I want to be able to put in the external ip address and the port and have it run app externally. It is currently possible to do this locally. Here is my code for the server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

var mysql   = require('mysql');

var connectionpool = mysql.createPool({
  host     : '127.0.0.1',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'development',
  port: 3306,
  connectionLimit: 50
});
var UAParser = require('ua-parser-js');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
})); // pull information from html in POST


require('./config/signup.js')(app, express, connectionpool, UAParser);

//Setup for external access
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res){
  //res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
  //res.end('It works');
}).listen(8080);

// Start app on port 8080
/*app.listen(8080);
console.log('Rest Demo Listening on port 8080');*/
```

At the moment I can connect to the server externally but I end up at the default homepage which is just a small bit of text. I want to be able to enter the external ip address and the port and have it start to run my app instantly without have to navigate through directory’s. I am also running apache if this is of any help.

FIXED:
This line of code instaed of the http.createServer function made it work

```
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Are you hitting the app directly w/ port 8080 or are you using Apache to proxy it with mod_proxy?

Comment: Sounds like you are hitting apache instead of node. kill apache and change 8080 to 80. you may have to get super user permissions to listen on that port.

Comment: connect to apache (port 80/8080) or mysql (3306) does not work?

Comment: Killed apache but when I try to listen on port 80 I get Error: listen EACCES. How do I get super user permissions to listen on that port?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust/create your apache configuration like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName (SERVER NAME HERE)
    ServerAlias  (SERVER ALIAS HERE)
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/nodejs-error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/nodejs-access.log" common

    #######################
    # Redirect to node.js #
    #######################
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass               /            http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse        /            http://localhost:8080/

</VirtualHost>
```

You should place this in your apache conf.d directory (usually /etc/httpd/conf.d) in a file like 'nodejs.conf'.

Edit: Note - if you are using the default apache config, it lives in the conf directory and is named httpd.conf. You can edit the VirtualHost entry in there to match above.

Comment: And this will allow me to run apache and nodejs together?

Comment: That's the idea - yes. Apache will proxy all requests through to node. This way you don't need to run nodejs with funky permissions.

Comment: Would that be the conf-enabled folder?

Comment: If you're actually hosting stuff with apache, then rather than setting the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse to root (/) you could set them to something else (/node) and it will only proxy to node for that path.

Comment: What linux distro are you using? On my debian/ubuntu/centos servers the configuration is located in /etc/httpd/conf and /etc/httpd/conf.d.

Comment: Im using Ubuntu. I have an lighttpd folder but no httpd folder. Strange.

Comment: It looks like it may be in /etc/apache2/conf-enabled or /etc/apache2/conf.d

Comment: Inside my apache2 folder I have folders conf-available, conf-enabled, mods-available, mods-enabled, sites-available and sites-enabled. I alos have files apache2.conf, envvars, magic and ports.conf. I cannot seem to find conf.d in any of them.

Comment: Apparently the file is apache2.conf but there is nothing in that file that resembles your code above. Should I just add it in? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Tried that but apache is telling me that proxy requests is a syntax error

Comment: Try to find the configuration that contains the virtualHost definition that is running on port 80.

I did this by going to /etc/apache2 and using grep to search for ":80" recursively. 

As in:

grep ":80" -r ./

It may be that with a default installation, this file is in sites-available and is named "default".

Comment: If it is in fact the default configuration, then you should be able to get away with just adding the proxy directives to the existing configuration.

Comment: You may also need to enable mod_proxy.

See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58179/install-of-mod-proxy-to-get-proxypass-to-work).

Comment: Thanks for everything. I must head off from work now but I will have a read of that tonight and let you know how I get on tomorrow. Thanks for all your help so far.